# Can a soul communicate through our dreams?

Tags: death, dream, soul, murder

My sixteen year old brother died recently. His death happened under mysterious circumstances and we've tried everything to find out what happened but unfortunately we can't find an answer. We all feel like it was a murder, is there a chance of his soul communicating to us through a dream, where he tells us what happened?